# How use math operations in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want use math operations in XAML code but I dont know how?

Comment: you're going to have to be a lot more specific for this question to make any sense.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? XAML is a markup language for the user interface. To perform (complex) calculations you'll need to write some code in the cs files.

Comment: What kind of math, and what would you be doing it on?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You mean you want to perform arithmetic operations in xaml?

check out [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/11/13/arithmetic-operations-in-xaml.aspx) (it comes with a sample project)

It allows you to specify code like this:

```
<TextBlock Height="{Binding ElementName=tb1, Path=ActualHeight,
  Converter={StaticResource JScript},
  ConverterParameter=Int32.Parse(values[0])/10 *100-110 }" Background="Red"/>
```