# WPF - Using a static resource in an expression

Tags: c#, wpf

The simplest of things, I'm sure but for the life of me I can't seem to find a solution for this. I am defining a double value for the width of my control like so:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="dbl_controlPanelWidth">420</sys:Double>
```

Now I would like to set a width of one control to one third of this width. Is there a way to do this? Something like:

```
<Button x:Name="btn_myButton" Width="{StaticResource dbl_controlPanelWidth} / 3"
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use converter. Or some layout *magic* (e.g. creating a grid with 2 columns, where first column is `"*"` and contains element to which `ActualWidth` you bind, and second column is `"2*"`).

Comment: I think that the best solution is to use markup extension, take a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/305932/Static-and-Type-markup-extensions  , exactly when call static methodes, hope this work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the height by setting `Source` property of `BindingExpression`.

```
  <Button x:Name="btn_myButton" 
            Width="{Binding Source={StaticResource dbl_controlPanelWidth}, 
                            Converter={converters:ScreenRatioConverter},
                            ConverterParameter='3'}"
```

By using so you can apply any of static sources or also `ViewModel` properties to them.

You can define a `ScreenRatioConverter` like this:

```
    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
    public class ScreenRatioConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
            private static ScreenRatioConverter _instance;

            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            { 

                double size = System.Convert.ToDouble(value) / System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return size.ToString("G0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            { 
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            {
                return _instance ?? (_instance = new ScreenRatioConverter());
            }

        }
```

Passing your factor value (3) as parameter gives you re-usability and flexibility to re-size your `width` anytime.

Comment: Sorry for replying with such a delay. Unavoidable, I'm afraid. Thank you for your answer though. I was aware of value converters being able of doing what I require but I was hoping there was an easier way. I ended up making my own converter, which allows the basic arithmetic operations. I used yours as a starting point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at this answer : [Do math in xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3491543/2363706)
Also this link is short and right to the point : [Arithmetic operations in Xaml](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/11/13/arithmetic-operations-in-xaml.aspx).

Comment: Indeed. The second link in particular is, as you put it, "short and right to the point". Thanks! However I ended up making myself a bit more complex converter, allowing all four basic arithmetic operations (+, -, * ,/).

Answer (score 0):

You can have expressions in bindings.

What you'll need to do is bind the width to the resource via a converter and code the expression into the converter:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            return (double)value / 3;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Then your XAML is just:

```
<Button x:Name="btn_myButton" Width="{StaticResource dbl_controlPanelWidth}" />
```

Comment: XAML should should show how to declare the converter and reference it in the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not adding new information but posting a solution I ended up with at the end, I'm posting an answer to my own question for other people to use. I hope that's fine. Not that experienced with SO yet.

So... I started with Niraj Doshi's code, expanded it a bit to support the basic arithmetic operations (+,-,*,/) and ended up with this:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Converter for simple math operations. It should be bound to a source path, which has a number for its value.
    /// the parameter should be a string with a format of "N|xxxxx" (without quotes), where N is a number, the '|'
    /// sign is a separator and the second parameter (xxxxx) is a string defining the operation. Valid values are
    /// add, subtract, multiply and divide. Below example shows how a button's width is set to one third of the
    /// parent's canvas width:
    /// <Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas" Height="220" Width="260">
    ///     <Button x:Name="button1" 
    ///                Content="Button" 
    ///                Height="30" 
    ///                Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="79" 
    ///                Width="{Binding ElementName=mainCanvas, Path=Width, 
    ///                                Converter={local:ScreenRatioConverter}, 
    ///                                ConverterParameter='3|divide'}"/>
    /// </Canvas>
    /// </summary>
    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
    public class ScreenRatioConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        private static ScreenRatioConverter _instance;

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string parameterString = parameter as string;
            string[] parameters = parameterString.Split(new char[] { '|' });
            double par1 = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
            double par2 = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameters[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string operation = (string)parameters[1];
            double result = 20; //Default value to return if anything goes wrong.
            if (operation.Equals("add"))
            { result = par1 + par2; }
            else if (operation.Equals("subtract"))
            { result = par1 - par2; }
            else if (operation.Equals("multiply"))
            { result = par1 * par2; }
            else if (operation.Equals("divide"))
            { result = par1 / par2; }

            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //Needs to be overridden because of inheritance from MarkupExtension.
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return _instance ?? (_instance = new ScreenRatioConverter());
        }

    }

}
```

Any comments about improvements or making the code safer/cleaner/... are welcome.